# Unable to edit the xml files on powercenter

Tags: xml, file, informatica

I'm working on an existing project which I have imported into Powercenter - XML files, but how to view and edit the columns and rows on XML definition?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To launch **XML Editor**, first you need to import the definition of the XML:

[image: screenshot]

Then click the XML definition and select Edit XML Definition to open the Powercenter XML Editor.

Comment: In the sources window in Designer